# Mixing Angular2, Backbone and MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-5

We have an existing MVC5 web app using, for the most part, Backbone with Backbone routing. When you reach the site, it loads the original basic home/index.html which loads all the Backbone scripts, etc.

We are introducing Angular2 (release: 2.0.1) to the mix and have a new index.html page for Angular being served up from our NgController.

Currently, we have the app using the Hash location strategy; once the app loads, the routing takes control of the URL and we go from something like:

```
http://blah.com/ng/#/reports
```

to

```
http://blah.com/#/reports
```

Which is generally fine, and browsing around within the angular app will change the url to /#/pageXyz etc.
... Until you attempt to refresh or deep-link directly to the latter examples, wherein the browser is technically just going to

```
http://blah.com
```

Which serves up the original Backbone index page.

What are the options for resolving this?

- Is it possible to have the Angular router prefix the routes with the ng controller, perhaps?
- Can Backbone redirect any /#/* routes to ng/#/* pages?
- Some particular mapping for the MVC routes that can recognise an Angular URL? (Though I believe #'s don't make the cut when it comes to URLs so can't match them in the routing?)
- Would switching to HTML5 URLs be better? (Better for MVC routing?)

Overnight, the Angular site appears to have gained an [incomplete teaser page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)  for setting up VS2015 (Note: we are using VS2013 currently), and at the very bottom leaves you on a cliffhanger seemingly related to the issue:

> Note on Routing Applications
>
> If this application used the Angular router, a browser refresh could return a 404 - Page Not Found. Look at the address bar. Does it contain a navigation url (a "deep link")? We'll have to configure the server to return index.html for these requests. Until we do, remove the navigation path and refresh again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually went with altering the Backbone routing.

Pros: It works and was only two lines:

```
#restore angular url
if location.pathname == '/' and location.hash.substring(0,2) == '#/'
    location.href = location.href.replace('/#/','/ng/#/')
```

Cons: On a refresh/deep link, you get two full page loads - first into home/index loading backbone, then into ng/index loading angular after the redirect.

Still, all things considered, the fact it works at all is good enough for me.